# Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=5000x5000>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>) to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
def preprocess(image_path):
    slide = OpenSlide(image_path)
    region = (1000,1000)    
    size = (5000, 5000)
    image = slide.read_region(region, 0, size)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (512, 512))
    image = np.array(image)    
    return image


train_x=[]
for i in tqdm(train_df['file_path']):
    x1=preprocess(i+i[61:75])
    train_x.append(x1)
```

Why I am getting this below error when I run ***tf.image.resize(image, (512, 512))***
?

***ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=5000x5000 at 0x7F0CB61EBE90>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>) to a Tensor.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slide.read_region(region, 0, size)` converts the image file into an "in-memory" representation of an image. The resizing Ops such as `tf.image.resize()` accept input images as tensors or np.array but you are passing a PIL image which causes the error. Kindly change the preprocess function like below

```
def preprocess(image_path):
    slide = OpenSlide(image_path)
    region = (1000,1000)    
    size = (5000, 5000)
    image = slide.read_region(region, 0, size)
    # convert the image to np.array
    image = tf.image.resize(np.array(image), (512, 512))
    return image
```

I could replicate the error with a single image in colab. Please refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/eae5cb20eeb761c542d15af7f8ae1b0c/untitled204.ipynb). Thank you!